# Upload multiple files at once

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax7, dynamics-365-operations

I'm looking to upload multiple (100+) files at once and then manipulate them sequentially (or even concurrently if there are no dependencies) using x++. I understand that there is the File::GetFileFromUser(), but I cannot select multiple files using this method, I can only do one file at a time, which for hundreds of files is not considered an acceptable solution by the customer.

Is there a way to select multiple files at the same time so that the upload can do many files at once? Or is it possible to select a folder and have it upload the contents of a folder to temporary storage?

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532893/6575455

Comment: @AliaksandrMaksimau That answer is for [tag:dynamics-ax-2012] and won't work for [tag:dynamics-365-operations].

Answer (score 2):

You could upload your 100+ files as a single archive and before processing files in X++, you would simply unpack the archive.
Otherwise you can log a feature request (ideally on ideas.dynamics.com).

Comment: Surprisingly simple yet elegant!

Comment: While this would probably work, I'm going to continue looking more into an extensible control because while it might satisfy the immediate requirement, it doesn't really solve the overarching technical limitation. It's definitely a solution though.

Answer (score 1):

There does not appear to be an easy way to do what you want, but D365 is still new and I don't know everything. I did want to provide you with some good resources that you may be able to figure it out from.

- File upload control - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/operations/dev-itpro/user-interface/file-upload-control
- Working with files (pt 1) - https://sertandev.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/how-to-work-with-files-in-ax-7-part-1-upload-download-reading-and-storing-files-in-db/comment-page-1/#comment-7
- Working with files (pt 2) - https://sertandev.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/how-to-work-with-files-in-ax-7-part-2-browse-and-download-files-stored-in-db-attach-files-to-new-document-management/

And I believe the javascript that launches with the browse button is located in `webroot\Scripts\Controls\Documents.js`.

I spent maybe an hour trying to figure this out, and I already found a bug and submitted it to connect https://connect.microsoft.com/site1321/feedback/details/3136255 .

If you end up figuring it out, I'd be happy to hear your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Dynamics AX 2012 supports multi-threading in batch jobs. I have not seen anything that shows 365 for operations does not.

http://www.artofcreation.be/2010/10/03/batch-multithreading/

Import a file with the file name of your 100+ files, then launch a new thread to load each file in parallel.

Comment: Unfortunately AX 365 and AX 2012 are too architecturally different to be compared in this case, especially as one resides in the cloud and the other resides locally (with a thick client)