# RunBase FilenameOpen field - allow multiselect file

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have simple RunBase Dialog:

```
Dialog dialog;
DialogField fieldFilenameOpen;

dialog = super();

fieldFilenameOpen = dialog.addField(extendedTypeStr("FilenameOpen"));
dialog.filenameLookupFilter(['xml','*.xml']);

return dialog;
```

Is it possible to set the dialog to allow the selection of multiple files?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640672/upload-multiple-files-at-once

Comment: @AliaksandrMaksimau yes, but this thread did not answer my question.

Comment: The short answer is no. How would you process multiple filenames anyway?

Comment: I thought the names would be passed to the container and I could iterate over them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't using standard AX AFAIK.

AX calls `WinAPI::getOpenFileName(...)`, which uses `COMDLG32.dll`. You could copy/modify that method according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/, but good luck!

You can use .Net pretty easily though. I just threw this job together in a few minutes, so make sure to read up on the control. For example, there are properties like `CheckFileExists` you might want. Error checking, etc. This should get you going though.

```
static void JobMultiselectDemo(Args _args)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    System.String[]     results;
    System.String       sysFilename;
    Filename            axFilename;
    int                 i;
    int                 fileCount;
    
    ofd.set_Multiselect(true);
    ofd.set_Title("Multiselect demo");
    ofd.set_DefaultExt("xml");
    ofd.set_Filter("XML Files (*.txt)|*.xml");
    ofd.ShowDialog();

    results = ofd.get_FileNames();
    
    fileCount = results.get_Count();
    for (i=0; i<fileCount; i++)
    {
        sysFilename = results.get_Item(i);
        axFilename = sysFilename;
        info(axFilename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally, i used button on RunBase Dialog.

```
protected Object dialog()
{
    dlgGroup        = dialog.addGroup('');
    buttonGroup     = dialog.formBuildDesign().control(dlgGroup.formBuildGroup().id());
    buttonControl   = buttonGroup.addControl(FormControlType::Button, 'A Button');

    buttonControl.text("Select files");
    buttonControl.registerOverrideMethod(methodStr(FormButtonControl, clicked),
                                         methodStr(MultiselectFileTest, selectFilesButtonClicked),
                                         this);

    return dialog;
}



private void selectFilesButtonClicked(FormButtonControl _formButtonControl)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;
    System.String[] files;
    System.String file;
    str fileName;
    int i, filesCount;
    ;

    openFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog.set_Multiselect(true);
    
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult::OK)
    {
        files = openFileDialog.get_FileNames();
    
        filesCount = CLRInterop::getAnyTypeForObject(files.get_Count());
        
        selectedFiles = conDel(selectedFiles, 1, conLen(selectedFiles));
        
    for(i=0; i<filesCount; i++)
        {
            file = files.get_Item(i);
            fileName = CLRInterop::getAnyTypeForObject(file);
            selectedFiles = selectedFiles + [fileName];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, it looks like you used my answer. If you could mark it as accepted, that would close out the question and help others.